# Iridescence effect in OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0. Replacing the black area

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-3.0

I am trying to apply an iridescence effect to an object. For this, I used the following shaders:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es 
uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix; 
uniform mat4 u_mvMatrix; 
uniform mat4 u_vMatrix;

in vec4 a_position; 
in vec2 a_textureCoordinates; 
in vec3 a_normal; 

out vec2 v_textureCoordinates; 
out float v_CosViewAngle;
out float v_LightIntensity;

void main() {
    // transform normal orientation into eye space
    vec3 modelViewNormal = mat3(u_mvMatrix) * a_normal;
    vec3 modelViewVertex = vec3(u_mvMatrix * a_position);
    mediump vec3 eyeDirection = normalize(-modelViewVertex);

    vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightPosition - modelViewVertex);
    lightVector = mat3(u_vMatrix) * lightVector;

    v_LightIntensity = max(dot(lightVector, modelViewNormal), 0.0);
    v_CosViewAngle = max(dot(eyeDirection, modelViewNormal), 0.1);
    ...
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision lowp float;

in vec2 v_textureCoordinates; 
in float v_CosViewAngle;
in float v_LightIntensity;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;

// wave numbers for the iridescence effect: k = 2.0 * pi / wavelength (nm).
const mediump float PI = 3.141592654;
const mediump vec3 rgbK = 2.0 * PI * vec3(1.0/475.0, 1.0/510.0, 1.0/650.0);
const mediump float iridescence = 4.4;
const mediump float minThickness = 80.0;
const mediump float maxVariation = 50.0;

void main() {
    float thickness = texture(s_texture, v_textureCoordinates).r 
        * maxVariation + minThickness; // or texture2D() - in OpenGL ES 2.0
    float delta = (thickness / v_LightIntensity) + (thickness / v_CosViewAngle);
    lowp vec3 color = cos(delta * rgbK) * iridescence * v_LightIntensity;
    vec4 resultColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
    outColor = resultColor;
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Question:** How to replace a black area with a common texture? In other words, to have a common texture instead of black color.

**Note:** I tryid as:

```
vec4 resultColor = texture(s_texture, v_textureCoordinates) * (vec4(color, 1.0) + 0.5);
```

And so:

```
if (color == vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) { // if black color
    resultColor = texture(s_texture, v_textureCoordinates);
} else {
    resultColor = texture(s_texture, v_textureCoordinates) * (vec4(color, 1.0) + 0.5);
}
```

But this did not solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

The code of the shaders is partially taken from PVRShamanGUI.

**Update:** 
Based on the Rabbid76 answer, I also used delta, but only to check the wavelength (in nm):

```
...
if (delta > 1700.0 || delta < 370.0) { 
    resultColor = texture(s_texture, v_textureCoordinates) * v_commonLight;
} else {
    resultColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
outColor = resultColor;
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is not completely black, the values of the color channels is not exactly 0.0. Compute the average color (gray scale) and [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) the color and the texture color dependent on the gray scale:

```c
vec4  texturColor = texture(s_texture, v_textureCoordinates);
float gray_scale  = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;  
resultColor = mix(texturColor, color, gray_scale);
```

Another possibility is to mix the color dependent on the value of `delta`:

```c
vec4 texturColor = texture(s_texture, v_textureCoordinates);
resultColor = mix(texturColor, color, delta);
```

Comment: The first variant helped me. Thanks You!

Comment: Based on your answer, I also used delta, but only to check the wavelength (added to the update). Not sure if this is correct in all cases, but it works well. Many thanks!